# Why can't I set digital IO of PIC16F628

Tags: led, pic

I want to thank you for reading this question , keep in mind it might seem silly but it has been troubling me for a couple of hours.

I am using a PIC16F628. All i am trying to do for now is turn a simple LED on.
I have created the following code using MikroC:

```
void main()
{
  TRISA=0x00;
  PORTA=0xFF;
}
```

Have simulated the following circuit with Proteus:
[image: Proteus Schematic]

I am aware that only 4 leds would light up.

An uploaded the code to the PIC and veryfied it using PICkit2 (Software and Programmer).

I have read that the Programming pin (RB4/PGM) should be set on low , which I have done.

The PIC is wired on testing board and it doesn't turn on any LED. None of the pins (RA0,RA1,RA2,RA3) give enough voltage (they give about 0.3V).

1)I am supplying the circuit with 5V.

2)I am using the correct pins.

3)I have reprogrammed it a couple of times , no success.

4)MCLR is connected through a resistor to Vdd.

5)PGM pin is connected to GND (Vss)

6)LED are the correct way connected (even tried to rotate them in case I had mistaken).

7)I have tested the wiring , it is not interrupted.

It doesn't work , and I don't know what to do. Could somebody ,please  explain what I have done wrong ?

Comment: If you're not using series resistors for the LEDs you may have fried the output pins when you first tried to turn them on. It doesn't take long!

Comment: I don't know mikroc and without all of your code it's hard to tell but... Have you set The config bits accordingly To your hardware or even at all?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell what's going on without showing us your entire code, and a schematic of your physical implementation.

However this is what you can look into:

1. You should add a for-ever loop at the end of your code. Your microcontroller might be shutting off after one run. Add at the end a `while(1)` or `for(;;)`
2. Try adding the following code to your initialization (or whichever format your micro controller header defines these registers)

`ANSEL  = 0; /* Configure analog pins as digital*/`

`CMCON  = 7;    /* Disable comparators*/`

3. I haven't used microchip controllers under MikroC, but are you sure it's `TRISA` and `PORTA` instead of `TRISO` and `GPIO`?
4. Make sure you configured the internal oscillator (INTOSC) appropriately. 
   You can configure it by settings bits 0-2 (FOSC2:FOSC0) of `CONFIG` register
   to either`101` or `100`for INTOSC

Comment: I have added a while loop , disbled comparators but ANSEL ,nor ANSELH, do not exist for this particular PIC. For MikroC the correct command is TRISA and PORTA , tried TRIS0 and GIP0 and   it does not understand the commands. Changed the PIC in case it was damaged and still no result.

Comment: Disable the watchdog

Comment: Watchdog Timer (WDT) already disabled . Highspeed Oscillator (HS) is enabled and Low Voltage Programing (LVP)s dissabled.

Comment: I have 100 Ohm resistors for a LEDs and 10K Ohm resistor for MCLR. I pressume it's ok.

Comment: We can skip the led concerns by removing hem completely and just probing the voltage output of these channels.

Comment: Interesting development , I accidentally made pins 15 and 16 touch (RA7/OSC1/CLKIN and RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT) for a brief moment (about a second) and the LEDs are on now. Could somebody explain this to me?

Comment: sounds like the internal oscillator is not selected...

Comment: @morty1993 HS (High Speed Oscillator) is not the internal oscillator. Do you have an external crystal oscillator set up? If not then you need to configure for INTRC mode, not HS mode.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what lancovici said:

- Do your LEDs have series resistors?
- What is the configuration word value you use?

A first step could be that you check your hardware setup with a know-working .hex file. There are a few (including two (with and without crystal) for the 628) at my age-old blink page: http://www.voti.nl/blink

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Wisp628 programmer. But the information could still be helpfull , thank you.

Comment: A .hex file is 100% programmer-independent. You can use any programmer you want to transfer a .hex file into your PIC chip.

Answer (score 1):

Your schematic shows now crystal or other clock source. This leads me to assume that you are intending to use the internal oscillator.

**However**, based on your comment on another answer, you say you have the configuration bits set to use `HS` mode. HS stands for High-Speed Crystal Oscillator/Resonator. In order for this mode to work, you need an 8MHz to 20MHz crystal or resonator attached to the OSCIN/OSCOUT pins. As you do not have this in your schematic (and so I assume do not have this set up), then you will have no clock source for your PIC to run on - and as such it will appear to do nothing at all.

For the internal 4MHz oscillator, the correct option is `INTRC` as per page 95 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40300C.pdf).

Try changing the setting to this and see if it starts working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`TRISA` and `PORTA` are in different banks, according to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40300C.pdf), so you  need to set the `STATUS` register properly before each access.

From "FIGURE 3-2: DATA MEMORY MAP OF THE PIC16F627 AND PIC16F628", `PORTA` is in *bank 0*, while `TRISA` is in *bank 1*.